# Appcelerator [ERROR] : Invalid "--device-id" value

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I'm building hello world application in Appcelerator studio. App starts OK in "Mobile Web Preview in Browser" and android emulator. When I'm trying to run it on my device I'm getting error:

```
[ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value "TA93002AYM"
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\.appcelerator\install\4.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\plugins\run.js:84:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

I get the same result with Titanium SDK 3.5.0 and 4.0.0. I have tried to restart computer, restart appcelerator studio, refresh project, clean project...nothing helps. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your phone correctly recognized by your pc? Check this via adb.

Comment: If it is not correctly recognized check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011685/cant-connect-nexus-4-to-adb-unauthorized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you [Robin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2439890/robin-ellerkmann) for pointing me to the right direction. `adb devices -l` revealed me that device was unauthorized. Killing `adb` and starting it again forced my phone to show USB debug prompt again.

Comment: Cool that I was able to help you. Welcome to SO. You should write this as a comment to my response. If an answer is the solution for your problem please mark it as accepted to make this clear.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this answer](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160877/testing-with-galaxy-s4-device---adb-shows-serial-not-model) you can try to use `ti build -p android -T device` from your project directory in the shell. This may do the trick.

You should check that your USB connection type is MTP and NOT PTP.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an actual phone and had this error, what I had to do was go to developer options on the phone and turn off USB Debugging and turn it back on to get things to working.  I also followed the steps above to kill adb and restart it.

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

I was using mac, so I set adb to the PATH to call it.  This is optional but convenient.  Refer to the answer here by Tobrun to learn how ([Trying to add adb to PATH variable OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526470/trying-to-add-adb-to-path-variable-osx))