# Adb can't detect Samsung Note Pro although I installed USB driver

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin, adb, xamarin.forms

I want to use Samsung Note Pro for debugging on Windows with Xamarin.Forms,
I installed Samsung USB Drivers
[from this address](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117#none) and turned on `developer mode`
but still not work. When I call `adb devices` my device didn't appear in the list.

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Comment: @mrbengi - did you turn on usb debugging?

Comment: @Giorgi , from where I can turn on usb debugging?

Comment: @mrbengi: Inside developer options there is usb debugging.

Comment: @mrbengi: Have a look at this image: http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/72/50/63533937566119/0/enable-developer-options-usb-debugging-your-samsung-galaxy-s5.w654.jpg

Comment: in the notification bar u can see usb connected option in that if it is selected now MTP change it to PTP. Try changing option like that and wait for 2mins after changing.

These worked for me. I to have same problem @mrbengi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As @Sreeraj's answer stated, installing Kia solves a lot of driver issues under Windows)

### Once `Developer Mode` is enabled:

> There is also a separate “Developers Options” section. The difference now is before you get to enable the USB debugging option, you must first enable or turn on “Developer Mode”

### Update:

> but when I call it gets the device as "unauthorized"

1) To allow app installs from non-Market apps, tap the menu button on your home screen, then choose Settings >> Applications >> Unknown sources.

2) [Can't connect Nexus 4 to adb: unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18011685/4984832)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This worked, now amd recognizes the device thanks but when I call it gets the device as "unauthorized", is this normal?

Comment: @mrbengi updated my answer, check the "Update:" section

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem once. Despite installing drivers from Samsung website, adb could not recognise my device. Then installing Samsung Kies software in my PC helped me. It may work.

Answer (score 1):

After you enable `Developer Mode` you need to turn on **USB Debugging** before you connect the device with your PC.

[image: Enable USB Debugging]

You can also debug without connecting your device via wireless: [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/239438)