# adb doesn't see device online, android studio does

Tags: android, adb

I have the opposite of this problem: [Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Android studio sees the device and can deploy to/ run on device no problem.

But I'm trying to use apache cordova and cannot see the device online from the command line.

```
adb devices
```

shows my device number, and "offline".

I've tried all of the recommended steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9966660/210757

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's highly odd, as all the other tools work by way of adb.  Any chance you have more than one version of adb installed on your system?  Or that your USB cable got bumped, or the connection is just flaky?

Comment: yep - I had adb in C:\program files(x86)\android\android-sdk, one in %USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk%, and one in a custom folder in my path. I kept the %USERPROFILE% one and deleted the others because I think that's the standard install location. I wonder if the program files one was installed by android studio. Everything appears to be working OK though.