# adb disconnect <ip-address >,disconnected the same device on the same server using by two user

Tags: android, adb

Two user connected same android device through putty.

After seen adb devices can seen device is connected to both the putty users.

Doing `adb disconnect <ip-address>` by one user on the same server by putty is disconnecting the other user putty devices too.

Example:

1. Both the user connected through linux server daddy.
2. Open putty both the user and connect the android device through ip address which is same.
3. Now if one user disconnect the android device by command `adb disconnect <ip-address>`, another user too disconnected.
4. run `adb devices`,can't see  any device connected through both the user.

Answer (score 2):

If different users have their different Android devices (different clients), you can make different user start their adb server in different ports to listen the connections. Then different users can control their clients without interfere with each others.

```
$ adb -P 5038 start-server
$ adb -P 5038 connect 192.168.1.100:7777
$ adb -P 5038 disconnect
```

If different users in your server connect to the same device (client), there is no way to let different users to control the device at the same time. The reason is the adb daemon on the device can only be allowed listen to one port when you start it with command `adb tcpip 7777`.